# Removing first x characters from string?

Tags: python, string

How might one remove the first x characters from a string? For example, if one had a string `lipsum`, how would they remove the first 3 characters and get a result of `sum`?

Comment: better example if the number of characters removed wasn't equal to the number of characters to remain.  e.g. `"lipsumm"[3:] == "summ"`

Answer (score 267, accepted):

```
>>> text = 'lipsum'
>>> text[3:]
'sum'
```

See the official documentation on [strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) for more information and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) SO answer for a concise summary of the notation.

Answer (score 26):

Another way (depending on your actual needs):
If you want to pop the first *n* characters and save both the popped characters and the modified string:

```
s = 'lipsum'
n = 3
a, s = s[:n], s[n:]
print(a)
# lip
print(s)
# sum
```

Comment: I guess it's metaphorically "popped" but actually its just 2 different slices, no real popping

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> x = 'lipsum'
>>> x.replace(x[:3], '')
'sum'
```

Comment: Note that this is longer in code and will also take more time since you have to search for the substring before you replace it.

Also: `>>> x = 'liplip'`
`>>> x.replace(x[:3], '')`
`''`. Sure you could fix this by having the third parameter (count) = 1 but it would still take longer.

Comment: nah it's related to your answer so it belongs here. You can add count=1 to yours so that it still works btw

Answer (score 4):

Use `del`.

Example:

```
>>> text = 'lipsum'
>>> l = list(text)
>>> del l[3:]
>>> ''.join(l)
'sum'
```

Comment: This doesn't work like you'd think `text = 'liplip'` `>>> text.lstrip(text[:3])` `''` because for one [`str.lstrip([chars])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) _The chars argument is not a prefix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:_

Comment: Neither of the solutions work eg. for `'liplip'`. In the second one `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion`

Comment: The 1st solution still does not work for the `'liplip'` example and the 2nd solution has overcomplicated everything. It's really hard to improve  the simple inbuilt `text[3:]`

Comment: hello U10-Forward, hope you don't mind, but I deleted the first solution posted as it was indeed incorrect for a general string.  The solution deleted *all* instances of the first x characters if the string contained repeats and thus could cause a bug if used.

Answer (score 1):

Example to show last 3 digits of account number.

```
x = '1234567890'   
x.replace(x[:7], '')

o/p: '890'
```

Comment: This has the same issue as the answer by tkbx

Comment: eg. `>>> x = '12345678901234567890'`
`>>> x.replace(x[:7], 'xxxxxxx')`
`'xxxxxxx890xxxxxxx890'`

Comment: Also this doesn't even answer the question, you are replacing characters with `x`s instead of deleting them