# How would I remove the Arabic prefix "ال" from an arabic string?

Tags: python, arabic

I have tried things like this, but there is no change between the input and output:

```
def remove_al(text):
    if text.startswith('ال'):
        text.replace('ال','')
    return text
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing first x characters from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806559/removing-first-x-characters-from-string)

Answer (score 2):

`text.replace` returns the updated string but doesn't change it, you should change the code to

```
text = text.replace(...)
```

Note that in Python strings are "immutable"; there's no way to change even a single character of a string; you can only create a new string with the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only remove the `prefix ال` and not all of `ال` combinations in the string, I'd rather suggest to use:

```
def remove_prefix_al(text):
    if text.startswith('ال'):
        return text[2:]
    return text
```

If you simply use `text.replace('ال','')`, this will replace all `ال` combinations:

*Example*

```
text = 'الاستقلال'
text.replace('ال','')
```

Output:

```
'استقل'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the method `str.lstrip` instead of rolling your own in this case.

example text (alrashid) in Arabic: `'الرَشِيد'`

```
text = 'الرَشِيد'
clean_text  = text.lstrip('ال')
print(clean_text)
```

Note that even though arabic reads from right to left, `lstrip` strips the start of the string (which is visually to the right)

also, as user [6502](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320726/6502) noted, the issue in your code is because python strings are immutable, thus the function was returning the input back

Answer (score 0):

"ال" as prefix is quite complex in Arabic that you will need Regex to accurately separate it from its stem and other prefixes. The following code will help you isolate "ال" from most words:

```
import re

text = 'والشعر كالليل أسود'

words = text.split()

for word in words:
    alx = re.search(r'''^
                            ([وف])?
                            ([بك])?
                            (لل)?
                            (ال)?
                            (.*)$''', word, re.X)
    groups = [alx.group(1), alx.group(2), alx.group(3), alx.group(4), alx.group(5)]
    groups = [x for x in groups if x]
    print (word, groups)
```

Running that (in Jupyter) you will get:

[image]