# Pathlib: how to remove first n characters of path.stem

Tags: python, pathlib

To the point:
In a python script with YAML syntax I want to rename a file using:

```
{created.year}-{created.month:02}-{created.day:02}_{path.stem}.jpg
```

Would it be possible to remove the first n characters of `path_stem`? If so, how?
Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you mean with the YAML syntax stuff. In general `path.stem` simply returns a string, which you can always edit like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11806564/4026792

Comment: Thanks. My question was how to remove the first n characters of that since I am a Python novice? In Bash one does   mv "$file" "${file%???????}"  to remove the first 7 characters. Is there an analog with Python and pathlib? :) Thanks!

Comment: That should be explained in the answer I linked, in your example that would be `path.stem[n:]` to remove the first n characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing first x characters from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806559/removing-first-x-characters-from-string)

Comment: When using path.stem[7:] I get the error "ERROR! Invalid format specifier" for the colon. When I remove the colon, then I only get the 7th character of the name.

Comment: Could you explain more about in which context you are using this script? You said something about YAML syntax, why do you mean by that? It doesn't look like standard python. PS: It's very confusing that the other commenter is also named Thomas ;)

Comment: Look at this: https://snipboard.io/TQgPdv.jpg It's from the organice tool: https://organize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page/actions.html#python. The you will have an idea of what I want to do :)